# Sqlalchemy How to count rows per month using sqlalchemy select()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this model:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, BIGINT, VARCHAR, TIMESTAMP

Table(
   'person',
   metadata,
   Column('id', BIGINT, nullable=False, primary_key=True),
   Column('name', VARCHAR(300)),
   Column('user_created', TIMESTAMP),
   Column('user_deleted', TIMESTAMP)
)
```

I would like to make a select that show how many user created per month. So with some research I came up with this query.

```
def count_users_by_month(user_table: Table):
   query = select(
      user_table.c.id,
      func.count(user_table.c.user_created).label('count'),
   ).where(and_(table.c.user_deleted.is_(None)))\
      .group_by(
         user_table.c.id,
         user_table.c.created_at,
         func.date_trunc('month', table.c.user_created)
      )
   return query
```

This query is executed in another method by `conn.execute(query)`.
The result I'm getting is:

```
(74, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 10, 19, 39), 1)
(75, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 10, 21, 24), 1)
(102, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 18, 46, 49), 1)
(141, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 6, 16, 12, 6), 1)
(443, datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 1, 11, 37, 29), 1)
(450, datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 1, 14, 16, 53), 1)
(487, datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 10, 42, 23), 1)
(509, datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 8, 10, 51, 55), 1)
```

So it kinda grouped all my rows by month, on this case I can see 4 rows grouped by March and 4 rows grouped by April, and count of 1 on each one. Not really what I would like to have. I would to know the total number of rows by month, like this:

```
(datetime.datetime(2020, 3), 4),
(datetime.datetime(2020, 4), 4),
...
...
(datetime.datetime(2022, 12), 10),
```

Before anyone ask, If I remove the `user_table.c.id` or `user_table.c.created_at` from my `group_by` I get an error saying `column "person.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to count the users ids in a month, ie. `func.count(users_t.c.id)`, not the timestamp itself.

I used a label for the `DATE_TRUNC` function so I can reuse it in the `group_by()` call.  The first label, `'users_created'` is unnecessary but just for clarity.

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    users_t = User.__table__
    # Label the data trunc expression so we can reuse it in group_by()
    # ie. DATE_TRUNC(...) AS month_group ... GROUP BY month_group
    stmt = select(
        func.count(users_t.c.id).label('users_created'),
        func.date_trunc('month', users_t.c.user_created).label('month_group')
    ).where(
        users_t.c.user_deleted == None
    ).group_by(
        'month_group')
    for users_created, month in session.execute(stmt):
        print (users_created, month)
```

#### SQL

```
SELECT 
    count(users.id) AS users_created,
    date_trunc(month, users.user_created) AS month_group 
FROM
    users
WHERE
    users.user_deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    month_group
```